# Visual Studio 2015: Unable to create universal application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, .net-core

I am stuck in creating an universal project under windows 10 using visual studio 2015 [image: screenshot].

I have tried everything from OS Reinstall to Windows Developer tools stand alone installer but had no luck.

The error I am getting is

> One or more projects require framework sdk .netcore , version = 5.0.

I have even installed KB3073097.exe which contains .netcore, version = 5.0

Comment: I assume you followed the [installation guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/07/29/building-apps-for-windows-10-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx), including the SDK?

Comment: Yes i followed each and every step

Comment: And what does happen if you click the Download button?

Comment: Nothing it opens microsoft.com they have even discounted support for nuget package manager

Comment: I also see that you have 3 updates available. Have you tried installing them?

Answer (score 1):

i have managed to simulate the problem you are experiencing by deleting the file **FrameworkList.xml** in the following path:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v5.0\RedistList**

After i deleted the **FrameworkList.xml** file i've got the same Error message you are receiving.

please check if you got that file in the path mentioned above.

also here is the contents of the file(if you want to create it manually)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileList Redist="Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.5.0" Name=".NET for Windows Universal" RuntimeVersion="5.0" ToolsVersion="4.0">
</FileList>
```

another option if you dont want to create it manually is by installing the [windows 10 sdk](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Sure thing i havent tried this will try it and let you know

Comment: I Have tried it its present but didnt worked. anyhow how did you fixed the error after deleting the folder form there do you have any setup to fix this issue.

Comment: I have saved the folder and all its contents and just copied it back. but i revised my answer please check and try it out, and update me if you managed to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Somebody seemingly found a solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f868b586-cffe-46d6-a453-95b014bce9ae/uap-project-not-creating?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
I think somebody seemingly found a solution at :

https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/35108/unable-to-target-windows-10.html

I hope it can help.. :)

Comment: I have done this all please mention a proper solution with Explanation like Sujania  said